# How to perform delete operation on infinite scroll with server side pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, pagination

I want to render a list of items using React and have implemented infinite scroll using react-intersection observer and pagination is implemented at server side. But I can also delete an individual list at any point. I am storing the data first in Context and for first page 1 I am simply adding it to context and for page > 1, I am appending to the context and mapping over them to render.

The problem that I am facing is if I delete a single list(row), and I paginate(scroll to other page) the page is incremented and api request is made with page 2 but I don't get the correct no of data for that page since 1 item was deleted the data in page 2 is reduced by 1 and became part of page 1, so I missed 1 item similary for subsequent no of delete also.

I want to know how to tackle this problem whether something needs to be changed at server side implementation for pagination(I am using JAVA Spring) or some additional query is required from frontend) or it's simply not good to perform delete on infinite scroll.

eg

Total no of items = 26(Page1=20 + Page2=6)
Items per page  = 20

Operations

1st api request page=1, data received=20, rendered on screen=20

1 item deleted so total = 25, rendered on screen=19

Scroll to page 2, 2nd api request page=2, data received 5(because 1 item was deleted), rendered on screen=19+5=24(so I have lost track of 1 item) and now the item is part of page 1 becuase of backend logic

Comment: It is difficult to follow what you're trying to explain if you don't show your code. Also: try to be more specific and explain in shorter paragraphs your current problem.

Comment: Please note that Java and JavaScript are two different languages.

Comment: Yes I know , I am using React at frontend and Java Spring at backend I am facing this issue and don't really know how to solve this whether it's a backend implementation limitation or could it be solved by sending some additional params from frontend.

Comment: hi, did u solve this issue?